# Map and List values from APEX SALESFORCE

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have question on my Salesforce WebService and Apex Code.

In a relationship, we have one Notice and multiple attachments in my salesforce. But I don't know how to fix below requirements:

1. when "GET" webservices incoming thru specific URL API, it supposed to return with JSON format
2. JSON Format should `{Notice1 : attach1{link},attach2{link} , etc }`

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/API/V1/notice/*')
global with sharing class API_Notice {
    
    @HttpGet(UrlMapping='/API/V1/notice/all')
    global static List<String> getNotice(){
        Set<Id> NoticeIds = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> VersionIds = new Set<Id>();
        String compares;    
        List<String> returnJSON = new List<String>();

        List<Notice__c> reConts = [select Id, ClosingDate__c ,Name, Contents__c from notice__c];
                        
        Map<Id,Notice__c> addMap = new Map <Id,Notice__c>(); 
        Map<Map<Id,Notice__c>,Map<Id,contentdistribution>> addsMap = new Map<Map<Id,Notice__c>,Map<Id,contentdistribution>>();
        //SET NOTICE ID 
        if(!reConts.isEmpty()){
            for(Notice__c nc : reConts){
                NoticeIds.add(nc.Id); 
                addMap.put(nc.id,nc);
            }               
        }
        
        //GET public Image URL 
        if(!NoticeIds.isEmpty()){
            Map<Id,ContentDocumentLink> contentMap = new Map<Id,ContentDocumentLink>([
                select contentDocumentid,LinkedEntityId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId IN:NoticeIds               
            ]);
            for(ContentDocumentLink Key : contentMap.values()){                                             
                VersionIds.add(Key.ContentDocumentId);                
            }
            if(!VersionIds.isEmpty()){
                Map<Id, contentdistribution> cdb = new Map <Id, contentdistribution> ([
                    select DistributionPublicUrl from contentdistribution where contentDocumentid IN:VersionIds
                ]);
               addsMap.put(addMap,cdb);
            }            
        }    
        return null;        
    }       
}
```